# Fetching Single Row in PL/SQL

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to create a new procedure in `Oracle SQL Developer` client. This procedure will fetch a single row on the basis of one condition.

My procedure code is as follow:-

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GETUSERKEYS 
(
  USERNAME IN NVARCHAR2 
, STATUS OUT NUMBER 
, TEMPTB OUT ClientKey%rowtype
) AS 
BEGIN
      SELECT * INTO TEMPTB FROM ClientKey WHERE ClientKey.USERNAME=USERNAME;
      STATUS:=1;
END GETUSERKEYS;
```

Here is my C# code:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("GetUserKeys", connection))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        OracleParameter username = new OracleParameter();
                        username.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;
                        username.ParameterName = "Username";
                        username.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        username.Value = Username;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(username);

                        OracleParameter status = new OracleParameter();
                        status.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
                        status.ParameterName = "Status";
                        status.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(status);

                        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                            connection.Close();
                        connection.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                        da.Fill(dataset);
                        _id = (int)cmd.Parameters["Status"].Value;
                        if (_id > 0)
                        {
                            if (dataset.Tables[0] != null && dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
                            {
                                _key = new ClientKey();
                                _key.ClientId = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ClientId"].ToString();
                                _key.ClientSecret = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ClientSecret"].ToString();
                                _key.ClientKeyId = int.Parse(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ClientKeyID"].ToString());
                                _key.Username = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Username"].ToString();
                                _key.CreateOn = Convert.ToDateTime(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CreateOn"].ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I am not able to figure out a way to return a row from a table based on condition.
I am new to Oracle.

Comment: The problem is C# does not support `%ROWTYPE` , so all you have open to you is work arounds. [Find out more](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3620578)

Comment: @APC what changes I have to make? I didn't get the Find out more link info.

Comment: To be clear, it's Oracle's C# client which doesn't support `%rowtype`. Anyway the simplest solution for you would be to use SYS_REFCURSOR , which maps to a `ResultSet`. One record is still a set. You probably don't want to go down the road of building Oracle user-defined types.

Comment: @APC it worked, thanks!! Please post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is [Oracle's C# client does not support `%ROWTYPE`](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3620578) , so you need to use a workarounds.

The simplest solution for you would be to use SYS_REFCURSOR , which maps to an ODBC `ResultSet`. One record is still a set. You probably don't want to go down the road of building Oracle user-defined types.

This [Oracle tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/williams-refcursors-092375.html) provides a starting point for using SYS_REFCURSOR with ODP.Net.